# is the theory of list decidable?

Tags: z3

I am wondering if the z3 theory of list decidable? It seems like we can only prove facts that are unsat but not sat using the theory, so I am curious if it is actually decidable. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you give examples of facts you can't prove? Are you using quantifiers?

Comment: Yes, for instance in the example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642565/cross-product-in-z3) you gave earlier trying to prove (assert (= (first (head l)) a)) would pretty much not terminate. So I am wondering if that has to do with theory of lists or quantifiers in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Z3, when we say a theory is decidable, we are usually talking about quantifier free problems. The theory of list implemented in Z3 is decidable. However, as soon as we use quantifiers and uninterpreted functions, like in question [cross product in z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642565/cross-product-in-z3), the problem becomes undecidable. Z3 can decide some fragments, but the problem described at [cross product in z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642565/cross-product-in-z3) is not in any fragment supported by Z3. Actually, Z3 will not be able to construct a model for any problem similar to this one. Thus, it will run forever trying to build a model, or will give up returning `unknown`. The result `unknown` may still be useful. In some cases, Z3 may produce a "candidate model". That is, an interpretation that does not satisfy all universal formulas in your problem, but satisfies all quantifier free formulas, and many instances of the universal formulas. To accomplish that, we have to disable the module MBQI. When MBQI is enabled, Z3 will keep trying to find an interpretation that satisfies all quantifiers.
Here is how we do it for you example:

http://rise4fun.com/Z3/kGtk

The trick is the following two commands I included in the beginning of the script:

```
(set-option :auto-config false)
(set-option :mbqi false)
```

I used the `get-value` command to show that the interpretation produced by Z3 satisfies `(assert (= (first (head l)) a))`. On the other hand, the interpretation for `append` does not really satisfies the universal formulas in this example.